# Regular expression to match a string between @@ in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java Pattern Compile to match substring with a specific pattern and add it to a List.

I want Regular expression to match the following scenarios

1. String starts and ends with (e.g. @@foo,bar,bla@@)
2. String starts with "@@ and ends with @@"
3. String starts with Hello "@@ and ends with @@", World
4. String starts with Hello "@@ and ends with @@",// This is a comment

The current code is:-

```
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@@([^@@]*)@@")
                 .matcher(content);
        System.out.println(m.find());
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.add(m.group());
    }
```

My content is `'<script> var bookSrc = "@@book:URL@@",var books_count: @@Count@@, var active = true</script>'`

The above code only matches the strings between @@ and the actual result is [@@count@@] and I expect the result to be [@@book:URL@@, @@count@@]

Any help would be appreciated, how should I modify my pattern to accommodate all of the above scenarios.

Comment: You are "eating" a `m.group()` because of the sysout of `m.find()` don't you think?

Comment: `[^@@]` isn't doing what you think. It matches any single character except `@`.

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("@@(.*?)@@")` (the question mark makes the .* non-greedy, so it will not consume the two @'s behind it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `Matcher.find` once before the loop is executed. Thererfore the first match is skipped. If you remove

```
System.out.println(m.find());
```

it works as expected. You can still test, if there were matches after the loop:

```
System.out.println(!matches.isEmpty());
```